# Cake PHP Table not found in datasource

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I added a table *sitewebs* in my existing database. So I created a class Model *Siteweb* :

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Siteweb Model
 *
 */
class Siteweb extends AppModel {
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'nom';
}
```

The connection parameters for the database are correct, and the user has all the rights on this table (When I generate the shema via command line `php cake.php schema generate -f`, although the table appears in the file shema.php).

**My Configuration**

- PHP 5.6.12
- MySQL 5.5.44
- Cake 2.1.3

**What I tried to do to solve the problem**

- Clear cache files from *app/tmp/cache/models* and *app/tmp/cache/persistent*
- Rename table and force it in Model file : `public $useTable = 'sites';`
- Grant All privileges to my MySQL user : `grant all privileges on mybase.* to myuser@'localhost';flush privileges;`

But I still have the error *Table sitewebs for model Siteweb was not found in datasource default.*

Look at the code of my controller :

```
$this->loadModel('Siteweb');    
try {
        var_dump($this->Siteweb->find('all'));
} catch (Exception $ex) {
        var_dump($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Except this controller, the application is functional.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set debug var to refresh cache files, solve my problem :

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```